# npm bin script isn't getting created correctly in Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I am creating a NPM package that could be used in command line. I am using npm's `bin` to specify my JS file to execute. Here's my package.json

```
"name": "textree",
"bin": {
    "textree": "./src/cli.js"
  },
```

However, when I run `npm link`, the batch command that's created by npm has content like this:

```
@"%~dp0\node_modules\textree\src\cli.js"   %*
```

And when I run the command, I am getting error:  */node_modules/textree/src/cli.js: No such file or directory*

If I examine other command line tools such as nodemon, their batch script has:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js" %*
)
```

Since my tool's batch script is not containing the similar code, it fails when I run it.

Any idea how to fix it? How do get npm to generate same script as in nodemon for my package too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I missed to add the hashbang line at the top of my "./src/cli.js" script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```